# jquery - using selector to find an href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Background Information:**

I'm trying to find the value in the attribute "row_id" in an href.  What will trigger this logic is when the user clicks on a "Save changes" button / image.

**Problem Description**

The jquery code I have right now is returning the contents of the second cell instead of the one with the href in it.  So from the HTML sample code below,  I need to extract 21586 from

```
 "<a href="index.php?page=row&amp;row_id=21586">Row SAA:HH1</a>"
```

**HTML Code**

The button that triggers the jquery logic is in the 4th cell of the row, and the row_id is in the href in the 5th cell.

```
 <tr>
    <td id="21581">
        <img src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-user-trash-16x16-gray.png" title="1 rack(s) here" height="16" width="16" border="0">
    </td>
    <td><div id="location_name">SAA:HH-123</div></td>
    <td><div id="row_name">SAA:HH1</div></td>
    <td>
         <input tabindex="1" name="edit" class="edit" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/pencil-icon.png" id="21581" title="Edit row" type="image" border="0">&nbsp;
         <input tabindex="1" style="display: none;" name="submit" class="icon" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-document-save-16x16.png" title="Save changes" type="image" border="0">
   </td>
   <td>
        <a href="index.php?page=row&amp;row_id=21586">Row SAA:HH1</a>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
    //save button handler
    $(".icon").click(function(e){
            //find the <a href that has the row id embbeded in it
            var row_id = $(this).parent().siblings().children($('a[href$="row_id"]'));
            console.log($(row_id).text());
    });
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you parse your href for the id?

Comment: @YaWang i need to first "find" the href via jquery ... then i can parse it

Comment: In jQuery `$=` means *"ends with"*, but the href doesn't end with `row_id`, it ends with `row_id=21586`. Are you looking for a filter to match the key and any number, or do you just want to find that number, or what, it's not that clear?

Comment: @adeneo, ah my bad. i just want to find that number and save it

Comment: Try `$('a[href*="row_id="]').attr('href').split('=').pop();`

Comment: Can you manipulate the html in the cell with the target href? If so, just add data-rowid="2158" and then in jquery you can call ...children('a[data-rowid]').data('rowid')

Comment: @bingo, i can't control the html.  it's someone else's code I'm just trying to add on to

Comment: @adeneo that works perfectly!  if you add as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this . Could be used universally for any url and parameter value.

```
$.getUrlParamValue = function(link, parameter){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + parameter + '=([^&#]*)').exec(link);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

var value  = $.getUrlParamValue ($("a").attr("href"),'row_id');
alert(value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2xsse9v/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vsLy0rfx/

```
$(".icon").click(function(e){
        //find the <a href that has the row id embbeded in it
        var row_link = $(this).parent().siblings().find('a[href*="row_id"]')
        var row_id = row_link.attr('href').split('row_id=')[1];
        console.log(row_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check the console, it returns 21586.
i used `.closest()` and `.find()` to navigate and find the `<a>` in the corresponding row. then i got the `href` attribute and split it to find the desired `id`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.icon').on('click', function() {
     var href = $(this).closest('tr').find('a').attr('href');
        var id = href.split('&')[1].split('=')[1];
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="21581">
            <img src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-user-trash-16x16-gray.png" title="1 rack(s) here" height="16" width="16" border="0"/>
        </td>
        <td><div id="location_name">SAA:HH-123</div></td>
        <td><div id="row_name">SAA:HH1</div></td>
        <td>
            <input tabindex="1" name="edit" class="edit" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/pencil-icon.png" id="21581" title="Edit row" type="image" border="0"/>&nbsp;
            <input tabindex="1" style="" name="submit" class="icon" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-document-save-16x16.png" title="Save changes" type="image" border="0"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="index.php?page=row&amp;row_id=21586">Row SAA:HH1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following

```
var result = $('a[href]',$(this).parent().parent()).attr('href').split("=").pop();
```

//result will be equal to 21586